# Can't remove repository from Xcode project

Tags: xcode, github, repository

I picked up another GitHub repository into my project when adding a file from another project through Xcode add file/copy and so on. I can't seem to find out what file it's pointing to despite deleting it from the project. Also, I can't seem to get rid of the extra repository. Any help in how to clean this up would be appreciated. I want to get rid of the ex-welcome-1 GitHub in this project. That said I do not want to get rid of ex-welcome-1 as it's own GitHub Xcode project. I just need to get these two separated. On the ex-login-1 Xcode project it has no reference to the Zentastic project so this is one way.

[image]